# How to make repeating lists up until a certain number of items

Tags: python, list

I'm indexing a dataset in python and want to generate a list repeating certain numbers up until a certain number of items in the list

There are a number of rows for my data set and i want to generate a list of [1,2,3,4,5] that repeats until it reaches the number of rows (in this case 90, but I'd like to make the code non-specific).
So it would be like [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,...] until there are 90 terms in this list. 
What's the most efficient way to do this? I've tried *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
lst = [i % 5 + 1 for i in range(N)]
```

Where `N` is the number of items you want (e.g. 90)

Answer (score 3):

Use `cycle`, which takes in an iterable and infinitely repeats it:

```
from itertools import cycle

r = cycle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
result = [next(r) for _ in range(90)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, ...]
```